# Test (sandbox?) credit card data for PayPal in-context checkout

Tags: paypal

PayPal dev doc provides a cool Plunker snippet demo for in-context checkout:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfNSVRyq86pDR5mH4HH?p=preview

```
 dummy code because unless this stackoverflow 
 do not enable to have a link to Plunker
```

As I understand correctly the buyer does not have to have PayPal account *at* *all* to accomplish the payment by using the 'Pay with Debit or Credit Card' button. *Please confirm I understand this correctly*

The question is: When integrating and actually testing a web site, how can I test this use case. I mean I suppose no real credit card data required here in the sandbox.

*I suppose this should not be confused with the sandbox demo account demo/test credit card data, because that credit card data is assigned with a (demo) PayPal account, and this data I am asking for is definitely should not.*

See attached pics and the dev doc link:

[image: in-context popup]

then credit card data input:

[image: credit card data input]

Here is the developer doc for in-context checkout:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you need to use one of the test card numbers that are associated with sandbox test accounts. Although it's a slightly skewed model of the real world, as far as your code is concerned, you shouldn't see any difference between one of these cards and an arbitrary card.

Work is underway to support industry standard test cards, but until that is complete you may see buggy behavior if you use them.